# Running one task from role

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I tried to run playbook with role and only few task from it.
F.e.
I have playbook

```
# setup.yaml

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: system
      tags: setup
```

and role "*system*" with tasks:

```
# roles/system/tasks/main.yaml

- name: Test ping
  import_tasks: ping.yaml
  tags: test
- name: Create ansible user
  import_tasks: create_user_ansible.yaml
  tags: setup
====================================================
# roles/system/tasks/ping.yaml   
                                                                                                            
- name: test_ping
  ping: 
====================================================
# roles/system/tasks/create_user_ansible.yaml  
                                                                                              
- name: Creating ansible user
  tags: setup
  user:
    name: ansible
    password: '<hash>'
    groups: adm
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash
    system: no
    createhome: yes
    home: /home/ansible
```

When I run command

`ansible-playbook -i inventories/setup setup.yaml`

both of tasks (ping.yaml and create_user_ansible.yaml) running
But when I run

`ansible-playbook -i inventories/setup setup.yaml --tags setup`

it works, like I need.

**So, my question**:

Is this that behavior, that Ansible developers design, or I made mistake in my playbook, and there are some way, to run only few tasks from role without using `--tags`  in command line?

Comment: See [Include Tasks of Role By Tag Or Filter In Ansible Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574687/include-tasks-of-role-by-tag-or-filter-in-ansible-playbook/).

Comment: Thanks, @VladimirBotka, I already knew about this function, but, to tell the truth, I don't like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Ansible. As shown in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html):

> By default, Ansible runs as if `--tags all` had been specified.

If you want a play to not run when you didn't specify any tags, you can add the special tag `never` to it. Again an example from the docs:

> Another special tag is `never`, which will prevent a task from running
> unless a tag is specifically requested.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> tasks:
>   - debug: msg="{{ showmevar }}"
>     tags: [ never, debug ]
> ```
>
> In this example, the task will only run when the `debug` or `never` tag is
> explicitly requested.

Comment: Yes, thanks, tag ```never``` really work. But, it doesn't seems like best practise, does it? But also I suppose, there are no better way?

Comment: Maybe there is a better way, but I don't know it.

Comment: Okay, thankful for your help. I wait some time, and if there are would no better answer, I will mark your answer as best :)

Comment: `always` and `never` are an elegant addition to the concept of tags.  For the very reason that OPs question asks.  How is this not a best practice?  It's especially useful and easy to comprehend in this 'debug' example.  

Otherwise you have to comment a bunch of stuff out, or remove it, once you're done debugging.  That's fine if you want to keep to a minimum number of lines.  If you just want to not run that code unless you call it, marking it with `['never', 'debug']` does exactly that.